# Open my app(Deep-link) from custom intent in JOVO

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, jovo-framework

I am using Jovo framework to develop Google-assistant actions

Here is the scenario I need,

1. Talk to My Notes. **Add "Hello world"**
2. Using Jovo framework and dialogFlow fullfillment, I captured ADD intent

```
    app.setHandler({

  ADD() {
    if (!this.getAccessToken()) {
            this.googleAction().showAccountLinkingCard();
        } else {
     this.toIntent('WelcomeIntent');
  }
});

module.exports = { app };
```

Now I want open my app with "Hello world" as parameter using deeplink

Could someone help me how can I open app/url from jovo framework

Thanks in advance